# httperf segmentation fault error on OS X 10.7.1

Tags: testing, load, httperf

When I try to perform a load test using httperf with high request rate, I get the following error:

```
» httperf --client=0/1 --server=www.xxxxx.com --port=80 --uri=/ --send-buffer=4096 --recv-buffer=16384 --num-conns=200 --rate=30
httperf --client=0/1 --server=staging.truecar.com --port=80 --uri=/ --rate=30 --send-buffer=4096 --recv-buffer=16384 --num-conns=200 --num-calls=1
httperf: warning: open file limit > FD_SETSIZE; limiting max. # of open files to FD_SETSIZE
**Segmentation fault: 11**
```

The error raises when the "rate" is > 15

Versions:

httperf 0.9.0

OS X 10.7.1

Comment: I see the same on OSX 10.6.8, with httperf 0.8.1 and 0.9.0

Comment: I see this, even with the rate set > 1. It seems to run a little longer before segfaulting at 2, but 3 segfaults wicked fast.

Comment: Check if you don't run out of memory.

Comment: Your system is running out of file descriptors. IIRC, this happens with RPM packages using a way too small `__FD_SETSIZE` (like 1024). Afaik you'll need to recompile the limiting RPM packages (e.g. glibc, Apache, PHP, etc.) to increase `__FD_SETSIZE`, so I'd suggest migrating the question to [sf].

Comment: I get this same issue on CentOS 6 x64 running Apache 2.2.15, but not Debian 6 x64 running Nginx 1.2.3, using httperf-0.9.0 on both. Open files limits are the same (1024) on both.

Answer (score 6):

As the warning states, the number of connections to the http server is exceeding the maximum number of allowed open file-descriptors. It's likely that even though `httperf` is limiting the value to FD_SETSIZE, you're reaching beyond that limit.

You can check the limit value with `ulimit -a`

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Try increasing the limit with `ulimit -n <n>`

```
$ ulimit -n 2048
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 2048
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

This is common practice on large web servers and the like, as a socket is essentially just an open file-descriptor.

Comment: As @Tom van der Woerdt/@m_pahlevanzadeh pointed out, replace `umlimit` with `limit` if you're using csh rather than bash/ksh

Comment: Thank you for the tips. But this doesn't solve the segmentation fault, and it is most probably not the root cause of the question. Reading the httperf documentation, it is actually aware of available file descriptors. It will log unavailable file descriptors and output them after one run. The program is not meant to crash if you run out of file descriptors.

Comment: Basho has a [convenient guide](http://wiki.basho.com/Open-Files-Limit.html) for raising the open file limit with steps for Lion. Basically, add `limit maxfiles 16384 32768` to a file called `/etc/launchd.conf` (create it if missing). Reboot. Check new value with `ulimit -a` or `launchctl limit`. I still get a segfault, though.

Comment: Doesn't work. I already have the following set:
`open files                      (-n) 640000`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `gdb` and use something like:

```
$ gdb httperf --client=0/1 --server=staging.truecar.com \
--port=80 --uri=/ --rate=30 --send-buffer=4096 \
--recv-buffer=16384 --num-conns=200 --num-calls=1
```

This will invoke `gdb` and you should see a `(gdb)` prompt.

Then: `run` and enter.

If it'll crash, type `bt` (backtrace). Investigate and/or share on here.

Comment: I have the same problem as the original question. Here is the output of your suggested gdb run: https://gist.github.com/2990517

Comment: IMHO, this could be another case where your system is running out of file descriptors. The other thing could be bad memory management in httperf. You could try to use [sysbench](http://sysbench.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: Probably this is a problem inside httperf. Sysbench is no use for me, since I want to test a webserver.

Comment: Eventually I ended up using partly siege and mostly tsung.

Answer (score 0):

`ksh` and `bash` are using *ulimit*, and `csh` is using the *limit* command.

Comment: Also use the lsof command to see open files and work this command with the following distro: AIX 5.3,
            FreeBSD 4.9 for x86-based systems,
            FreeBSD 7.0 and 8.0 for AMD64-based systems,
            Linux 2.1.72 and above for x86-based systems and 
            Solaris 9 and 10. @yesterday